# How do I close a window with a command/keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, openbox

I have openbox, but I want to use the i3 close shortcut (Mod+Shift+Q).
How do I do this using a command that I can link to the shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind keys.
Key and mouse bindings are created in your `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`
You need to copy file from `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` to `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`  if that file does not already exist.
then you need to add your combination in `<keyboard>` section

```
  <keybind key="M-S-s">
    <action name="Close"/>
  </keybind>
```

I'm not sure if M-S-s is right combination.